# How to change UIWebView keyboard toolBar in iOS 7?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiwebview, uikeyboard

`UIWebview`keyboard contains next,previous buttons like (<,>). I need to add a custom toolBar for`UIWebView` KeyBoard toolbar. Please advise me. I customised in iOS 8 but it is not working for iOS 7.

```
- (void) addCustomToolBarForWebViewKeyBoardToolBar 
{    

UIWindow *keyboardWindow = nil;

for (UIWindow *testWindow in [[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows]) {
    if (![[testWindow class] isEqual : [UIWindow class]]) {
        keyboardWindow = testWindow;
        break;
    }
}

// Locate UIWebFormView.
for (UIView *possibleFormView in [keyboardWindow subviews]) {

    if ([[possibleFormView description] hasPrefix : @"<UIInputSetContainerView"]) {
        for (UIView* peripheralView in possibleFormView.subviews) {

            for (UIView* peripheralView_sub in peripheralView.subviews) {

                if ([[peripheralView_sub description] hasPrefix : @"<UIKBInputBackdropView"] && peripheralView_sub.frame.size.height == 44) {
                    [[peripheralView_sub layer] setOpacity : 0.0];

                }
                // hides the accessory bar
                if ([[peripheralView_sub description] hasPrefix : @"<UIWebFormAccessory"]) {

                   UIToolbar *toolBar  = [self findWebKeyboardToolbar:peripheralView_sub];

                    if (toolBar){
                        editableToolBar=toolBar;
                        [self checkSelection:self];
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}    

}

- (UIToolbar *)findWebKeyboardToolbar:(UIView *)parent
{
if ([parent isKindOfClass:[UIToolbar class]]) {
    // the stock toolbar contains a single item with a UISegmentedControl customView.
    UIToolbar *tb = (UIToolbar *)parent;
    return tb;
}

for (UIView *view in parent.subviews) {
    UIToolbar *tb = [self findWebKeyboardToolbar:view];
    if (tb) return tb;
}

return nil;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use this category class it will help you.

```
@interface UIWebView (GUIFixes)

/**
 *  @brief      The custom input accessory view.
 */
@property (nonatomic, strong, readwrite) UIView* customInputAccessoryView;

/**
 *  @brief      Wether the UIWebView will use the fixes provided by this category or not.
 */
@property (nonatomic, assign, readwrite) BOOL usesGUIFixes;

@end


#import "UIWebView+GUIFixes.h"
#import <objc/runtime.h>

@implementation UIWebView (GUIFixes)

static const char* const kCustomInputAccessoryView = "kCustomInputAccessoryView";
static const char* const fixedClassName = "UIWebBrowserViewMinusAccessoryView";
static Class fixClass = Nil;

- (UIView *)browserView
{
    UIScrollView *scrollView = self.scrollView;

    UIView *browserView = nil;
    for (UIView *subview in scrollView.subviews) {
        if ([NSStringFromClass([subview class]) hasPrefix:@"UIWebBrowserView"]) {
            browserView = subview;
            break;
        }
    }

    return browserView;
}

- (id)methodReturningCustomInputAccessoryView
{
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wundeclared-selector"
    UIView* view = [self performSelector:@selector(originalInputAccessoryView) withObject:nil];
#pragma clang diagnostic pop

    if (view) {

        UIView* parentWebView = self.superview;

        while (parentWebView && ![parentWebView isKindOfClass:[UIWebView class]])
        {
            parentWebView = parentWebView.superview;
        }

        view = [(UIWebView*)parentWebView customInputAccessoryView];
    }

    return view;
}

- (void)ensureFixedSubclassExistsOfBrowserViewClass:(Class)browserViewClass
{
    if (!fixClass) {
        Class newClass = objc_allocateClassPair(browserViewClass, fixedClassName, 0);
        IMP oldImp = class_getMethodImplementation(browserViewClass, @selector(inputAccessoryView));
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wundeclared-selector"
        class_addMethod(newClass, @selector(originalInputAccessoryView), oldImp, "@@:");
#pragma clang diagnostic pop

        IMP newImp = [self methodForSelector:@selector(methodReturningCustomInputAccessoryView)];
        class_addMethod(newClass, @selector(inputAccessoryView), newImp, "@@:");
        objc_registerClassPair(newClass);

        fixClass = newClass;
    }
}

- (BOOL)usesGUIFixes
{
    UIView *browserView = [self browserView];
    return [browserView class] == fixClass;
}

- (void)setUsesGUIFixes:(BOOL)value
{
    UIView *browserView = [self browserView];
    if (browserView == nil) {
        return;
    }

    [self ensureFixedSubclassExistsOfBrowserViewClass:[browserView class]];

    if (value) {
        object_setClass(browserView, fixClass);
    }
    else {
        Class normalClass = objc_getClass("UIWebBrowserView");
        object_setClass(browserView, normalClass);
    }

    [browserView reloadInputViews];
}

- (UIView*)customInputAccessoryView
{
    return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, kCustomInputAccessoryView);
}

- (void)setCustomInputAccessoryView:(UIView*)view
{
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self,
                             kCustomInputAccessoryView,
                             view,
                             OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN);
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

iOS 7.x didn't have a UIWebFormAccessory class ,so you can't find it,just replace your code with follow
     - (void)addCustomToolBarForWebViewKeyBoardToolBar {
    UIWindow *keyboardWindow = nil;

```
for (UIWindow *testWindow in[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows]) {
    if (![[testWindow class] isEqual:[UIWindow class]]) {
        keyboardWindow = testWindow;
        break;
    }
}

UIToolbar *toolBar =  [self findWebKeyboardToolbar:keyboardWindow];
toolBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
}

- (UIToolbar *)findWebKeyboardToolbar:(UIView *)parent {
if ([parent isKindOfClass:[UIToolbar class]]) {
    // the stock toolbar contains a single item with a UISegmentedControl customView.
    UIToolbar *tb = (UIToolbar *)parent;
    return tb;
}

for (UIView *view in parent.subviews) {
    UIToolbar *tb = [self findWebKeyboardToolbar:view];
    if (tb) return tb;
}

return nil;
}
```